# Mouse not working after plug usb devices to virtualbox

Tags: usb, virtualbox

i having trouble when i plug USB device, including flashdisk to Virtualbox. when i plug it, mouse stopped moving it cursor ( means the mouse stopped working ), but keyboard still working. so i tap alt+f4 to close all program, then it work again. i check my flash drive, no virusses or malware, but what make this happen and how to fix this problem? host OS: WinXP SP3 guest: XP SP3

Comment: Have you enabled capture usb devices, specifically the mouse?

Comment: no, that was not the problem, the true problem is when i plug usb devices like flash disk, etc. my mouse freeze except keyboard, this happen to my VM even my Host OS.

Comment: Is your mouse directly connected to your mainboard or through a usb hub?

Comment: its connected to usb hub. why?

Comment: oh, i forget, windows detect it as Virtualbox usb, but  'found new hardware' wizard start, and i dont know how to find this driver

Comment: The usb hub may not be giving enough power to all devices causing them to not be registered properly. You should unplug the mouse from the hub and connect it to your pc. Same applies for the keyboard. These 2 devices should in general always be connected to your pc rather than a hub as they draw power from the usb port itself.